# Smooth Julia set for quadratic polynomials

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

This question is related to a classification of rational maps in terms of properties of their Julia set.

Let $f= z^2 + c$, with $c\in \mathbb{C}$ be a quadratic polynomial such that its Julia set $J(f)$ is connected.

- Q1: If there exists a relatively open set of $J(f)$ that is (the support of) a smooth curve. Is $f$ conjugate (resp equal) to a Tchebychev polynomial or power map $z^2$?
- Q2: Is the answer to Q1 yes under the additional assumption that $J(f)$ is also locally connected?
- Q3: If the answer to Q1 is no, can one describe the set of such counterexamples in terms of the parameter $c$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to a) is yes, and this was proved by Fatou in 1919. 
[Sur les équations fonctionnelles
Bulletin de la S. M. F., tome 48 (1920), p. 208-314](http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1920__48__208_1.pdf).
There are many generalizations of this fact. For one generalization, and further references you may look to
[Meromorphic functions with linearly distributed values and Julia sets of rational functions, Proc. AMS. 137 (2009), 2329-2333.](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/real-2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't gone through Fatou's argument yet but I am more convinced now that it is in fact true.

Comment: I don't see yet why the Julia set being equal to a circle or an arc of a circle implies that the answer to Q1 is yes but I will try.

Comment: @Gari: This is explained  in Fatou, http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1920__48__208_1.pdf

Answer (score 5):

From [this paper of Bedford and Kim](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01456.pdf) (arxiv link):

Fatou showed that if the
Julia set $J$ is a smooth curve, then either $J$ is the unit circle, or $J$ is a real interval. If $J$ is the circle, then $f$ is equivalent to $z → z^d$
, where $d$ is an integer with $|d| ≥ 2$; if $J$ is the interval, then $f$ is equivalent to a Chebyshev polynomial.

Comment: They take $f$ arbitrary holomorphic. What's meant by "is the unit circle"? If one conjugates $z\mapsto z^2$ by an affine map, one can get any circle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I wasn't able to track down the statement using their reference. Maybe it is somewhere in Milnor and I have overlooked it.